# How can I get the HTML content of a URL?

Tags: android, android-xml

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse((new URL(myUrl)).openStream());
```

I get exception with this....

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in your manifest?

Comment: Please put the exception here...

Comment: I get "null exception". It happens when I try to get stream.

Comment: And I have internet permission in my manifest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
....
URL url = new URL(myURL);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(input);
```

Inspired by [URLConnection getContent() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179658/urlconnection-getcontent-return-null)